# Intersection multiplicity via parametrization in general

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, singularity-theory, analytic-geometry

My question is a generalization of [Analytic and algebraic definitions of intersection multiplicity of two complex algebraic curves coincide](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/361856/analytic-and-algebraic-definitions-of-intersection-multiplicity-of-two-complex-a).

Take two complex space germs $(A, 0)=V(I_A)$ of dimension $a$ and $(B, 0)=V(I_B)$ of dimension $b$ in $\mathbb{C}^{a+b}$, where $I_A$ and $I_B$ are ideals of $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{C}^{a+b}, 0}$. Consider the algebra
$$ \frac{\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{C}^{a+b}, 0}}{I_A +I_B},$$
whose dimension is a candidate of the intersection multiplicity of $A$ and $B$ at $0$.

**First question:** In which cases and in which sense is it really the intersection multiplicity? (E.g. complete intersections, Cohen--Macaulay property...)

Assume that we have a parametrization $\phi: (\mathbb{C}^a, 0) \to (\mathbb{C}^{a+b}, 0)$ of $(A, 0)=\mbox{im}(\phi)$. Analogously with the case of curves, another candidate for the intersection multiplicity is the dimension of the algebra
$$ \frac{\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{C}^{a}, 0}}{\phi^*(I_B) \cdot \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{C}^{a}, 0}}.$$

**Second question:** Is it true that the two candidates are equal to each other? Are the two algebras isomorphic?

I tried to prove the isomorphism starting from the observation
$$I_A=\ker (\phi^*: \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{C}^{a+b}, 0} \to \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{C}^{a}, 0}),$$
yet unsuccessfully. I am interested in references as well.